# Put variables on <style> tag or directly on CSS file

Tags: css, angular

Guys I need to use an `<style>` tag inside a component.
Is there a way I could make this work:

```
<div *ngIf="hasAdjusts">
    <style>
        #titleText1, #titleText2{
            font-size: {{adjusts.title_fontSize}};
        }
    </style>
</div>
```

The explanation on WHY this is looong and boring. I know about [ngStyle], etc. Just want to know at least how to put my variables on css.. If its not possible through `<style>` maybe directly on `.css/.scss` file

Comment: ngStyle is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to read the official [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

In your case `[ngStyle]` does not work because you're trying to apply style to children of the component (element that are on the component's template).

So you can:

- add your style to the external CSS/SCSS file and reference it in `styleUrls`
- add your style in the inline `styles`

I Generally prefer having external files

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION 1**

You can assign the CSS directly to your elements, e.g.:

```
<div style="background-color:lightblue">
  <h3>This is a heading</h3>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

---

**SOLUTION 2** (What I would do)

This can be done the exact same way by including a CSS-file.
Put this in between your `<head>`-tags:

```
<link href="pathtoyourcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

HTML:

```
<div class="mydiv">
  <h3>This is a heading</h3>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mydiv {
background-color:lightblue
}
```

Comment: Also if is not explicit in the question, the author is asking about Angular solution

Comment: @MassimoCosta AFAIK styling Angular can be done the very same way as styling ordinary HTML elements.

Comment: you're right. you can use standard way to style components. So your answer works to. But Angular add some features on top of standard way.
For instance if you can isolate your styling